# Why do I get HMS Awareness Error Code 10102?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

When I am Running HMS Awareness code getting an Getting an Exception Error "com.huawei.hms.kit.awareness.b.HHG:Error Code:10102 Desc:". After giving required location permission in the manifest, I am getting the same error code 10102.

Answer (score 1):

It is required to provide/grant the location permission for both the creating application and **HMS Core app** .

Use the [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/awareness-awarenessstatuscodes) For more about Awareness status codes